# Turn off azure container monitoring

Tags: azure, monitor, azure-container-instances

Looking into the cost management apparently, we are exceeding the limits on our Storage Account, photo on this [link](https://prnt.sc/vojmez). From what I researched it is due to the fact that Azure by default does a lot of requests for "insights" on performance / availability etc...

How do I turn this off?

I am running a Container Instance, two containers actually  I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl) from the documentation. I did a research but couldn't find anything like my case. Any help?

Comment: What do you research that makes you consider it's due to the insights? Can you share the research?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes, here is the [link](https://stackify.com/remove-application-insights/) where is well described what I want to do. Something like the last section on this article but not for Azure app services, just for Container Instances, if its possible

Comment: @CharlesXu one more question, can I turn off the insights in the Storage Account?

Comment: Do you mean the Application Insights for the Storage account? If you mean it, then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as I know, Azure Container Instance does not have the Application Insights extension to monitor in default. It is only costed by its [vCPU and memory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-instances/) if you do not add the metric to monitor. So I think what you need to care about is the Container Instance itself and other Azure resources you use, not the Application Insights for Container Istance.